# git submodules with rails directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, git-submodules

I'd like to split up rails using a git submodule, which as far as I can tell, works basically like a directory. While this works well with a file structure similar to Python's Django, where each module has a models.py, views.py, etc, this doesn't appear to work so well with rails, which gives you a directory structure where there is a views folder, a controllers folder, etc, with each folder having 1 file from the module.

Is there any way to convert to a file structure similar to Django's, or if not, how would you use git submodules with rails?

Answer (score 0):

> how would you use git submodules with rails?

You would not use them, not directly at least. A git submodule is a repo, checked out in its own folder.

If you couple it with a *deployment* script which would linked (symlink) files from the rails directory structure to the files from that submodule folder, then you could get a rail app.